# Interface implementing it's own method

Tags: vb.net, interface

We recently came across an interface that looks similar to this in our solution. When we upgraded to VS 2015 it caused build issues. We believe the code is safe to remove, but want to be sure nobody else could think of why this would be valid code, or unsafe code to change (We would remove the implements on all of these)?

```
Public Interface IMyInterface
    Property p1 as string Implements IMyInterface.p1
    Property p2 as string Implements IMyInterface.p2
    Property p3 as string Implements IMyInterface.p3
    Property p4 as string Implements IMyInterface.p4
    .
    .
    .
End Interface
```

Just not sure why or how an interface method can implement a property on itself.

Comment: What's the "build issue", are you having errors?

Comment: Yeah. It is a build error. VS 2015 is installed on a colleague's computer and he is not currently at his desk so I can't get you the error number. I'll re-post when he is back

Comment: @the_lotus I am getting error code `BC30273 'Implements' is not valid on an interface property declaration` which when performing a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Visual+studio+BC30273&rlz=1C1GTPM_enUS588US589&oq=Visual+studio+BC30273&aqs=chrome..69i57.4200j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=Visual+studio+%22BC30273%22) pulls up about absolutely nothing

Comment: Well, that code works in 2013, seems like it's something new but I don't have any source to confirm. Maybe [this could help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbewhbd3(v=vs.90).aspx) (looks like this never should've worked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Visual Basic reserved word Implements is used in two ways. The Implements statement signifies that a class or structure implements an interface. The Implements keyword signifies that a class member or structure member implements a specific interface member.

You should remove the `Implements IMyInterface.p_` part of the property declarations.

Comment: Any thoughts about why this was previously working? Was it just a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, but it seems like something the compiler would ignore and that it was just updated to throw an error in the updated compiler.